# MySQL no inicia tras corte de energía eléctrica

Tags: mysql, windows10, innodb

He implementado un sistema que utiliza MySQL 8 como motor de base de datos y en dos meses han ocurrido 3 cortes de energía. Al encender el equipo nuevamente, el servicio de MySQL no es iniciado automáticamente y me he visto obligado a forzar la recuperación de InnoDB con **innodb_force_recovery = 2** para recuperar el acceso a la base de datos. El servidor tiene instalado Windows 10 y todas mis tablas usan InnoDB. La configuración de MySQL es la predeterminada a excepción de las siguientes directivas (my.ini):

```
innodb_ft_min_token_size = 2
lc_time_names = 'es_AR'
lower_case_table_names = 2
```

Los primeros dos cortes ocurrieron durante la mañana temprano antes de que el usuario comience a utilizar mi sistema, por lo tanto MySQL estaba "en reposo" (idle) y no había ninguna transacción en proceso ni pendiente de escribir en el disco.

Estoy intentando descubrir la causa de este problema pero no encuentro información suficiente.
He probado cambiando los valores de **innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown** y **innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup** para evitar que MySQL utilice archivos antes de tiempo pero al encender el equipo noto que MySQL igualmente realiza modificaciones tan pronto es iniciado.

También he desactivado la caché de escritura en disco desde el Administrador de dispositivos de Windows esperando que solucione el problema, pero no puedo estar seguro hasta que se produzca otro corte de energía (y tampoco quiero arriesgarme a realizar pruebas de este tipo en mi equipo de desarrollo, que es el único que tengo para trabajar).

Ya he aconsejado a mi cliente comprar un nuevo UPS/SAI porque el que usa actualmente tiene sus baterías agotadas, pero me gustaría llegar al origen de este problema porque me resulta extraño que un motor de base de datos sea tan frágil, especialmente cuando tengo la certeza de que el motor simplemente ha estado esperando conexiones en los primeros dos cortes. Esto me hace asumir que probablemente el responsable sea el sistema operativo, ya sea porque no escribe en disco algunos cambios o porque al reiniciar el equipo ejecuta alguna tarea de recuperación.

Si alguien puede aportar algún dato adicional o experiencias relacionadas con este tema estaré muy agradecido.

**PRIMERA EDICIÓN:** Añado el error que aparece en el log de MySQL (archivo *.err) cuando el servidor es iniciado, ya sea automática o manualmente.

```
2020-07-14T11:33:32.760738Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\MySQL\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.20) starting as process 3688
2020-07-14T11:33:33.005279Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-07-14T11:33:36.476226Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2020-07-14T11:33:37.132226Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060
2020-07-14T11:33:37.432990Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting XA crash recovery...
2020-07-14T11:33:37.450230Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] XA crash recovery finished.
2020-07-14T11:33:38.404853Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-07-14T11:33:38.453690Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] C:\MySQL\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.20'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2020-07-14T11:33:38.768328Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013183] [InnoDB] Assertion failure: dict0dict.cc:3344:for_table || ref_table thread 5308
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
11:33:39 UTC - mysqld got exception 0x80000003 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Thread pointer: 0x1ade21dcdc0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
7ff6a9e4de82    mysqld.exe!my_sigabrt_handler()[my_thr_init.cc:372]
7ffdef61cb7d    ucrtbase.dll!raise()
7ffdef61db81    ucrtbase.dll!abort()
7ff6aa04fc60    mysqld.exe!ut_dbg_assertion_failed()[ut0dbg.cc:98]
7ff6aa0270cb    mysqld.exe!dict_foreign_add_to_cache()[dict0dict.cc:3344]
7ff6aa06662b    mysqld.exe!dd_table_load_fk_from_dd()[dict0dd.cc:3407]
7ff6aa065dbf    mysqld.exe!dd_table_load_fk()[dict0dd.cc:3455]
7ff6aa05872f    mysqld.exe!dd_open_table_one<dd::Table>()[dict0dd.cc:4232]
7ff6aa056a32    mysqld.exe!dd_open_table<dd::Table>()[dict0dd.cc:4370]
7ff6aa066cdb    mysqld.exe!dd_table_open_on_dd_obj()[dict0dd.cc:378]
7ff6aa067c0a    mysqld.exe!dd_table_open_on_id_low()[dict0dd.cc:525]
7ff6aa067621    mysqld.exe!dd_table_open_on_id()[dict0dd.cc:641]
7ff6aa166955    mysqld.exe!row_purge_parse_undo_rec()[row0purge.cc:913]
7ff6aa16615c    mysqld.exe!row_purge()[row0purge.cc:1162]
7ff6aa16809d    mysqld.exe!row_purge_step()[row0purge.cc:1239]
7ff6aa15c0af    mysqld.exe!que_thr_step()[que0que.cc:923]
7ff6aa15b8c7    mysqld.exe!que_run_threads_low()[que0que.cc:977]
7ff6aa15b668    mysqld.exe!que_run_threads()[que0que.cc:1011]
7ff6a9f374d8    mysqld.exe!trx_purge()[trx0purge.cc:2251]
7ff6a9f2a8a7    mysqld.exe!srv_do_purge()[srv0srv.cc:2896]
7ff6a9f2e458    mysqld.exe!srv_purge_coordinator_thread()[srv0srv.cc:3059]
7ff6a9fba6c5    mysqld.exe!Runnable::operator()<void (__cdecl*)(void)>()[os0thread-create.h:103]
7ff6a9fbaa45    mysqld.exe!std::thread::_Invoke<std::tuple<Runnable,void (__cdecl*)(void)>,0,1>()[thread:40]
7ffdef5d0e82    ucrtbase.dll!_beginthreadex()
7ffdf1bf7bd4    KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk()
7ffdf234ce51    ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (0): 
Connection ID (thread ID): 0
Status: NOT_KILLED

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

**SEGUNDA EDICIÓN (21/08/2020):** Hoy ocurrió otro corte de energía (a 10 minutos de encender el equipo) y MySQL nuevamente no fue capaz de iniciarse. Esta vez, la caché de escritura en disco estaba deshabilitada desde el Administrador de dispositivos de Windows, así que descarto esa configuración como una solución al problema. A continuación adjunto el evento que aparece en el visor de Windows. Espero que mi cliente adquiera un UPS/SAI pronto, aún así cuando tenga la posibilidad evaluaré el comportamiento de otro motor de base de datos (probablemente PostreSQL) en situaciones de este tipo.

```
Nombre de registro:Application
Origen:        Application Error
Fecha:         21/8/2020 8:09:05 a. m.
Id. del evento:1000
Categoría de la tarea:(100)
Nivel:         Error
Palabras clave:Clásico
Usuario:       No disponible
Equipo:        SERVIDOR
Descripción:
Nombre de la aplicación con errores: mysqld.exe, versión: 8.0.20.0, marca de tiempo: 0x5e8338d2
Nombre del módulo con errores: mysqld.exe, versión: 8.0.20.0, marca de tiempo: 0x5e8338d2
Código de excepción: 0x80000003
Desplazamiento de errores: 0x0000000000edde82
Identificador del proceso con errores: 0xdd0
Hora de inicio de la aplicación con errores: 0x01d677ab3a45fe2d
Ruta de acceso de la aplicación con errores: C:\MySQL\bin\mysqld.exe
Ruta de acceso del módulo con errores: C:\MySQL\bin\mysqld.exe
Identificador del informe: 2869874e-040c-411b-8a9b-6527fda42a4b
Nombre completo del paquete con errores:
Identificador de aplicación relativa del paquete con errores:
```

Comment: En realidad no puedes esperar que un sistema que se está apagando de pronto quede estable, así no haya nadie conectado a él... tienes el problema del cache de escritura _a nivel de sistema operativo_ más la metadata que el servicio tenga que persistir cuando le haces shutdown. En fin... no puedes esperar que la DB haga milagros si se va la electricidad... es como esperar que un sistema sea 'seguro" pero sin garantizar el acceso físico a un equipo (un sistema puede ser seguro, no implica que haga milagros). Puedes considerar mover la DB a un host externo?

Comment: Gracias por responder. Entiendo lo que dices y lo he tenido en cuenta al formular mi pregunta. El problema es que el servidor MySQL no es capaz ni siquiera de iniciarse sin intervención mía, cuando en realidad no hubo pérdida de datos alguna. Esto no me ha sucedido, por ejemplo, con SQL Server. Lo que busco es alguna manera de que MySQL no quede en un estado inconsistente que le impida ser iniciado, al menos en esas situaciones donde nunca estuvo trabajando realmente y solo estaba esperando conexiones.

Comment: has hecho _algo_ para configurarlo previamente como servicio como lo indica la documentación oficial? [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-8.0-en/windows-start-service.html) Lo otro, has pensado en usar windows server en vez de windows10 (recomendación más que obligación)?

Comment: @Alfabravo No entiendo a qué te refieres con "hacer algo para configurarlo como servicio". MySQL está instalado como servicio y es iniciado tan pronto inicia Windows, al igual que mi servidor web Apache. No he considerado usar la edición Server de Windows porque el equipo es utilizado por un único usuario que también utiliza el equipo para otras tareas, la infraestructura de la empresa no justifica un servidor separado. Tampoco tengo certeza de que Windows Server vaya a realizar algo diferente a Windows 10 en estas situaciones.

Comment: Es que en tu pregunta no es claro si está configurado como servicio. No lo mencionas y dices que no arranca; había que aclararlo. Sobre el OS, la gestión de servicios y de recuperación sí es mucho más robusta, además que sí hay varios eventos que no quedan correctamente configurados o no son igual de estables en un W10 común y corriente. Igual, revisa el visor de eventos del OS y los logs de mysql y edita tu pregunta con cualquier registro relacionado (yo miraría los registros del tiempo en el que intenta arrancar de nuevo)... sin logs es difícil establecer una solución sin opinar

Comment: En mi pregunta se leé "al encender el equipo nuevamente, el servicio de MySQL no es iniciado automáticamente", por eso no creí necesario ser más explícito sobre eso. Editaré mi pregunta con el error que aparece en el log de MySQL y cuando tenga acceso al servidor de producción revisaré el log de Windows.

Comment: En mi empresa también tengo eventos regulares asociados a cortes de energía eléctrica, pero mis servidores no son Microsoft, son Linux yo te recomendaría la opción de usar Linux para tu server MySQL, cuando tengo un corte de luz lo único que hay que hacer es encender las maquinas y ya, tal vez en todo el tiempo que invertirás investigando el problema, ya lo habrías solucionado instalando Linux.

Comment: @RobertoPaillao Estoy considerando Linux para el servidor a futuro, a mí personalmente me parece más confiable, pero en este momento no es una alternativa y mi pregunta está enfocada en buscar una solución en el entorno actual (un solo equipo, un solo usuario, Windows) donde no hay requisitos exigentes, solamente que el servicio de MySQL sea capaz de arrancar por su cuenta tras un corte de energía cuando no hubo pérdida de datos y cuando no estaba realizando una operación específica desde mi sistema.

Comment: Estas usando Disco Solido ?

Comment: No hay que olvidar que un servidor de base de datos es, en primer lugar, **un servidor**, y un servidor nunca, nunca, nunca, debiera sufrir un corte de energía. Hay motores que son más o menos resistentes a estas cosas, si pudieras cambiarlo sugeriría que utilices _firebird_, que es super estable y resistente, incluso con un corte a mitad de muchas transacciones. Pero ningún servidor de base de datos te garantiza que pueda arrancar después de un corte de energía, incluso cuando no tienen usuarios conectados (como ya has podido experimentar).

Comment: Hay UPS con la protección mínima que son tan baratos, que una posible solución es que la llamada de soporte para resolver estos problemas le salga casi tan cara como comprar un UPS al cliente. Luego de pagar 5 o 10 veces lo que le costaría un UPS, te aseguro que va a preferir comprarlo.

Comment: @toto No, el servidor utiliza un disco duro tradicional (HDD).

Comment: Según [este artículo](https://ixnfo.com/en/recovering-mysql-innodb-after-power-failure.html) MySQL no arrancaría porque en el corte de energía las tablas (incluyendo la tabla de usuarios de MySQL), pudieron haberse dañado. Allí se dan algunas indicaciones sobre cómo resolver el problema. Como ya han comentado algunos, hay que cuidar que estos cortes ocurran en la máquina que aloja el servidor de BD, así que ponte serio con el usuario (debes incluso exigirle que instale un UPS decente al menos para el CPU)...

Comment: ...Una solución que se me ocurre, en el caso EXTREMO de que haya que dejar el servidor a merced de los cortes de luz, es que escribas un script que suba la base de datos de nuevo, recuperando la tabla de usuarios (si verificas que efectivamente ese es el problema por el que no funciona). En cualquier caso, toda pseudo-solución a este problema será siempre precaria, porque la solución es asegurar que no haya cortes en el servidor, sí o sí.

Comment: yo opino que se compre un generador eléctrico a gasolina... y una batería de back up que le de soporte vital eléctrico al equipo... mi mama opina que te mudes de ciudad... saludos. aunque la pregunta describe un problema tanto de software como de hardware; esta pregunta tendrá respuesta basadas en opiniones ya que el entorno es inestable.

Answer (score 1):

Es dificil mantener una base de datos con InnoDB totalmente saludable con cortes de energia repentinos. Sin embargo ademas de los consejos e indicaciones que se han dado, puedes revisar algunas configuraciones para controlar de mejor manera como se controla el flush del log de transacciones para evitar problemas.

Aqui un par de variables de configuracion y documentacion al respecto:

- `innodb_idle_flush_pct` controla la cantidad de operaciones de flush. Puede ser util para [controlar la utilizacion del disco en estado idle](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-buffer-pool-flushing.html#innodb-limit-flushing-rate).

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_idle_flush_pct

- `innodb_log_writer_threads` Fue introducido en Mysql 8 para mantener hilos de proceso exclusivos para escritura de log. Puedes intentar desactivarlo si el sistema es de baja concurrencia

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_writer_threads

Existe otra seccion que enumera varias estragegias para optimizar la escritura de los logs que podria ayudar en varias situaciones:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimizing-innodb-logging.html

Answer (score 0):

MySQL revisa al arrancar y, si algún bloque InnoDB no encaja con el checksum correspondiente, el arranque falla. Y el checksum va a fallar si la BD no alcanzó a persistir en disco todo lo que tenía pendiente en el *innoDB pool*.

La primera solución es garantizar que el OS pueda enviarle la señal a MySQL para que se detenga, persista todo y cierre el mysqld. Eso es, una UPS.

La segunda solución para *reducir* la posibilidad de errores es cambiar el tamaño del buffer pool. Eso seguro afecta el rendimiento, de seguro, pero dejará menos cosas pendientes de persistir.

Habría que revisar entonces los valores de estas variables y reducirlos:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
innodb_log_file_size = 5M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
```

De paso, revisa dónde estás variando la configuración, pues es llamativo que nos cuentes que 'al encender el equipo noto que MySQL igualmente realiza modificaciones tan pronto es iniciado'. Eso significa que estás modificando la configuración en el lugar incorrecto.

Si [revisas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36071309/mysql-crash-on-startup) en [detalle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34674680/repetitive-mysqld-exe-crashes-os-error-number-995-mysql-exception-0x80000003) en SO, no hay [otras](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=25506) [opciones](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=48192) para ésto más que recuperar los daños y continuar. Así pues, busca que no suceda. En cualquier DBMS vas a tener el mismo lío de corrupción de datos si el buffer pool / redo log / wal file / comosellameenmssql no se logra persistir, la BD relacional va a quedar en estado inconsistente y no va a cumplir con su promesa de ser ACID.